# Java :How Generic Erasure Works

Tags: java, arrays, generics, type-erasure

> Scenario A.java-----------after erasure-------->M.class
>
> Scenario B.java-----------after erasure-------->M.class

Then why A is illegal and B is legal since they have almost the same M after erasure.

Scenario A before erasure:

```
 class ArrayList<V> {
 private V[] backingArray;
         public ArrayList() {
             backingArray = new V[DEFAULT_SIZE]; // illegal
           }
 }
```

Scenario A after erasure:

```
 class ArrayList<V> {   
   private Object[] backingArray;   
      public ArrayList() {
      backingArray = new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE]; // this is not useful   
   } 
}
```

actually the Object[Default_Size] is useful ~
Scenario B before erasure:

```
class ArrayList<V> {
  private V[] backingArray;
  public ArrayList() {
    backingArray = (V[]) new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE]; 
  }
}
```

Scenario B after erasure:

```
class ArrayList<V> {
  private Object[] backingArray;
  public ArrayList() {
    backingArray = (Object[]) new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE]; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that Scenario A is illegal is that Java's covariant arrays are *not* implemented via erasure. This:

```
Object[] foo = new String[4];
foo[0] = new Object();
```

will raise an [`ArrayStoreException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html) at run-time, because `foo` refers to an array instance that *knows* it's a `String[]` (even though it's referred to via the variable `foo`, which has compile-time type `Object[]`). So this:

```
new V[4]
```

is illegal, because the run-time won't know what type of array instance to create.

Comment: so you mean the code Scenario A after Erasure  is wrong ? because `backingArray = new V[DEFAULT_SIZE];` will not become `backingArray = new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE];`

Comment: As you saw, it gives a compile error. So it won't become anything: not `new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE]`, and not anything else. It's just like how `new V()` can't become `new Object()`.

Comment: thanks very much , And another question about this ,do you think it will be fine if compiler compile Scenario-A-before into Scenario-A-after? I think there will be no difference if compiler just convert V->Object.

Comment: If `V` is `String`, then the example @ruakh gives could cause an `ArrayStoreException` under certain conditions. But basically, arrays and generics just really play badly together.

Comment: Oh~@LouisWasserman  and  @ruakh  thanks so much !! i'm clearer now.